# No perder referencia a una tabla en una funcion recursiva en LUA

Tags: lua

Mi tabla:

```
local table = {
    tablePlayer = {
        ["Volcam"] = "Druid",
        ["Chaman King"] = "Paladin"
    }
}
```

Mi funcion recursiva

```
local function func(t)
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            return func(v)
        else
            if k == "Volcam" then
                v = "Master"  -- CHANGE VALUE
            end
        end
    end
end

func(table) -- mando a llamar a la funcion y le mando la tabla como parametro
```

Quisiera no perder refencia a la tabla que le paso desde un principio y que se vean reflejados los cambios al momento que termine la funcion recursiva

```
print(table.tablePlayer.Volcam) -- RESULTADO: Druid, RESULTADO ESPERADO: Master
```

Comment: Pero no estás cambiando ningún valor en la tabla, sólo una variable local `v` que no produce ningún efecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es que estas cambiando el valor de la variable `v`. El problema es que `v` no está referenciando a ningun lado, es la copia de el value. Lo que debes hacer es cambiar directamente el valor de la tabla.

En Lua, si tu asignas una variable con otra variable, automaticamente la variable va a pasar a compartir direccion en memoria con la otra.

Solucion:

```lua
local table = {
    tablePlayer = {
        ["Volcam"] = "Druid",
        ["Chaman King"] = "Paladin"
    }
}

local function func(t)
    for k, v in pairs(t) do
        if type(v) == "table" then
            return func(v)
        else
            if k == "Volcam" then
                t.Volcam = "Master"
            end
        end
    end
end

func(table) 

print(table.tablePlayer.Volcam)
```

Resultado: `'Master'`

[image: LUA]